# Can't figure out how to delete the numbers that I have generated with onPressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a simple program with a Plus Button and a Minus Button that generates numbers successively. Generating the numbers with the Plus Button works totally fine but, I tried to delete the numbers with the Minus Button but can't figure this out.

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

// the state of the stateful widget is the one that holds the data and the ui of the widget
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  List<int> numbers = [];

  int counter = 0;

  void onClickedPlus() {
    setState(() {
      numbers.add(numbers.length);
    }); //setState function is a function that we use to notify our state class that the data has changed
  }

  void onClickedMinus() {
    setState(() {
      numbers.remove(numbers.length);
    }); //setState function is a function that we use to notify our state class that the data has changed
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(
            0xFFF4EDDB), //Color.fromRGBO => red, green, blue, opacity
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Click Count',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              for (var n in numbers) Text('$n'),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 40,
                    onPressed: onClickedPlus,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 40,
                    onPressed: onClickedMinus,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline_rounded),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

Current App UI : -

[image]

I'm expecting to delete the numbers successively with clicking the Minus Button.

Answer (score 0):

`List.remove(item)` removes the first occurrence of value from this list.

So `numbers.remove(numbers.length);` is not removing the last number because `numbers.length` is always greater than the last number in the list by one. Instead, you should use `List.removeLast()`.

```
void onClickedMinus() {
  setState(() {
    numbers.removeLast();
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written the remove case will always fail. Let me explain why,

your list is of length 0 at first and 1st add button will add 0 to the list.
Next add button will add 1 to the list.
Now, when you click on minus button the length is 2 but the list only contains [0,1].
So this will never work.
Instead,

you can write

```
void onClickedMinus() {
    setState(() {
      numbers.remove(numbers.length-1);
    }); //setState function is a function that we use to notify our state class that the data has changed
  }
```

this will delete the last element from the list.